# how to fetch data when package structure deleted in source, but in couchbase document, _class with old package structure is present

Tags: deserialization, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Few of the mapper classed moved to different packages, so how I can I retrieve the old documents with _class in my couchbase document.

Hi, I tried to follow the steps related to couchbasetypemapper, and mappingcouchbaseconverter to ignore the _class in my couhbase document which is old package structure in which that package is deleted.

Few of the mapper classed moved to different packages, so how I can I retrieve the old documents with _class in my couchbase document.

While retrieving from couchbase repository using findById, those converters are not being called at all to troubleshoot. Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an @TypeAlias attribute with the value of the (now removed) fully qualified class name.